# Работа с сетью в qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Например в консольных программах на языке си или c++ я могу использовать работу с сетью постепенно. Ну тоесть.

```
[Авторизация]
Отправка данных и получение.
[Обмен данными]
Отправка данных и получение.
```

Как видно отсюда я использую два способа сетевых функций, один раз для авторизации, другие разы для обмена уже данными.

И я всё думал а как на qt такое сделать? Ведь там устанавливаються сигналы. Но если я сделаю два сигнала, то оба будут принимать данные. Если один сигнал для авторизации, то как мне получать данные после авторизации?
Я ещё новичок в qt. Из-за некоторых причин редко пользовался им ( почти не пользовался ).

Comment: Что за 2 сигнала и почему они оба будут принимать данные? Какой у вас признак, что пользователь авторизован?

Comment: "Как видно отсюда я использую два способа сетевых функций" - отсюда ничего не видно, если честно. Вообще не понятно о чём идёт речь, есть только догадки.